# Format for searching by date

Tags: feature-request, search, dates, help-center-proposed

As described on the [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) you can search by date using format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

> [image: abs-date]

But turns out that another format:

```
MM-DD-YYYY
```

is also acceptable. I know that such format is used in USA, but for the first time it is a little bit confusing, especially when I met it on Stack Overflow in Russian. E.g. I could not expect that searching for [`created:10-05-2015`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A10-05-2015) gives a results for `5 oct 2015`, not a `10 may 2015`.

Could you please reflect in the help page that `MM-DD-YYYY` can also be used? Or forbid such format for searching completely as it done for incorrect dates like `22-22-2015`?

Comment: YYYY-M-D also works. Actually this would be the definitional format when the leading zeroes are not required. So if we are going to update this, then let's annotate all the formats that are acceptable.

Comment: Not sure it's a great idea to document and encourage people to use weird non-standard ambiguous date formats, even if they do sometimes work. This kind of thing is *why* ISO 9601 has the ordering it does: it's almost completely unambiguous, unlike mm-dd-yyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, and so forth. No reason to suggest people use anything else, really.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you probably mean 8601. My request has two options. Did you read the last sentence?